# Marklogic with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, marklogic

I'm trying to connect to Marklogic via SpringBootApplication.As a part of spring application,properties are defined in application.properties file.I have given the below four properties in properties file and trying to use it in configuration file.But while running the application,its not recognizing the marklogic database and throws the exception as

```
"Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class"
```

```
mlHost=localhost
mlUsername=admin
mlPassword=admin
mlRestPort=7000
```

```
package com.example.springboot;

import com.example.springboot.domain.Product;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory;
import com.marklogic.client.document.JSONDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.document.XMLDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.io.JAXBHandle;
import com.marklogic.client.query.QueryManager;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPDigestAuthFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class MarklogicConfiguration {

    @Value("${mlHost}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${mlRestPort}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${mlUsername}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${mlPassword}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DatabaseClient getDatabaseClient() {
        try {
            // TODO: is this really (still) required?
            // configure once before creating a client
            DatabaseClientFactory.getHandleRegistry().register(
                    JAXBHandle.newFactory(Product.class)
            );
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(host, port, username, password, DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST);
    }

    @Bean
    public QueryManager getQueryManager() {
        return getDatabaseClient().newQueryManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public XMLDocumentManager getXMLDocumentManager() {
        return getDatabaseClient().newXMLDocumentManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JSONDocumentManager getJSONDocumentManager() {
        return getDatabaseClient().newJSONDocumentManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public String getMarkLogicBaseURL() {
        return String.format("http://%s:%d", host, port);
    }

    @Bean
    public Client getJerseyClient() {
        Client client = Client.create();  // thread-safe
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
        client.addFilter(new HTTPDigestAuthFilter(username, password));
        return client;
    }


    /**
     * The entrance point to the sample application, starts Spring Boot.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MarklogicConfiguration.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Spring Boot app is expecting to configure a JPA DataSource, but it can't find the details it needs to do so. There's not a MarkLogic implementation of a DataSource, so you likely need to disable that aspect of Spring Boot. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source for information on excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration .

Comment: I have used spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration property and its worked for me.It will stop the default DataSource initialization as a boot startup.Thanks rjrudin

Answer (score 0):

Check this example (and the whole project) of how to connect to MarkLogic from within SpringBoot:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/grove-spring-boot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/marklogic/grove/boot/auth/AuthController.java

```
DatabaseClient client;

client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(markLogicConfig.getHost(), markLogicConfig.getRestPort(),
                    new DatabaseClientFactory.DigestAuthContext(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
```

...
if it worked, you should be able to do this:
...

```
client.newJSONDocumentManager().read(userDocumentUri, new InputStreamHandle());
```

userDocumentUri should be a document URI that exists in your DB and the user's role can access it...